# Rails generator: change directory of generated JS and CSS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I like to place controller-specific JS and CSS assets in app/assets/javascripts/controllers and app/assets/stylesheets/controllers, respectively (note the extra 'controllers' folder at the end).

Is there are easy way to configure the default Rails controller generator to place the JS and CSS stubs in the correct place? Right now, I need to move them into the 'controllers' folder manually after generation.

Comment: I don't know how to change the path directly, may be you need a hack to Rails.... But, you can write a customized generator that generate the asset to your own path, and then redefine the workflow of scaffold, it supported by Rails officially. see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow. Hope it will inspire you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you should do following things:

1st, run `rails g generator rails/my_assets`

2nd, change generated file (lib/generators/rails/my_assets/my_assets_generator.rb) content to

```
class Rails::MyAssetsGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  def create_assets_file
    create_file "app/assets/javascripts/controllers/#{file_name}.js", <<-FILE
  your content
    FILE
    create_file "app/assets/stylesheets/#{file_name}.css.scss", <<-FILE
  your content
    FILE
  end
end
```

3rd, add this lines to application.rb

```
config.generators.assets :my_assets
```

In this code you change default Rails assets generator. You can find more about it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this doesn't seem to be working in Rails 4.2.5. I've followed the instructions, but when I run `rails g assets ...` the behavior is the same as before.